# Using express middleware only for a GET request

Tags: node.js

The way I understand it, if I do something like:

`app.use('/something', function(req, res, next) {
    // some content here
});`

This basically means that if there's a request to 'something', then the middleware (my function) is executed before the next function.

So if I have something like this to handle a GET request,

`app.get('/something', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log('hello');
});`

Then 'hello' is going to be printed out after my original function has finished executing.

But how do I make it so that my middleware function is just executed when I ONLY make a GET request and not a POST request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `GET` only middleware, just do the following

```
// Get middleware
app.get('/something', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('get hello middleware');
    next();
});

// GET request handler
app.get('/something', function(req, res) {
   console.log('get hello');
   res.end();
});

// POST request handler
app.post('/something', function(req, res) {
    console.log('post hello');
    res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/something', your_middleware, function(req, res, next) {
   console.log('hello');
});
```

Only during the post request your_middleware will be executed.

your_middleware should be a function as follows:

```
function(req, res, next){
    ....
    next()
}
```

you can pipe in as many middlewares you want in this way for a specific route and request type